# Azure Storage Account - Cloning File shares?

Tags: azure, azure-files, azure-storage-account

I have an Azure Storage Account and currently using File Shares with some folder structure, I need to create another Azure Storage Account with exact File Shares with some folder structure. How would I clone the existing Azure Storage Account that includes the File Shares with some folder structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using **azcopy**?
I think it is a great tool for copying files across Azure File Storage shares.
You can copy an entire share as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#file-copy

Comment: Can I copy only the file shares folder structure?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar **azopy** from version [v10.4.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/releases/tag/v10.4.0) is able to copy empty directories, using `--include-path` and `--include-pattern` you can specify what exactly should be copied. Here you have useful options [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy#options)